# Why always linearly independent (Berlekamp Massey algorithm)?

Tags: linear-algebra

We consider the sequence, $(a_n)_{n \geq 0}$ generated by linear recurrence formula.

The generating function can be written as $\frac{f(X)}{g(X)}$ where $\deg g=n$ and $\deg f \leq n-1$. Without losing generality, we can set $[X^0] g(X)=1$.

According to Berlekamp Massey algorithm, in order to determine the coefficient of $f(X)$ and $g(X)$, we need only first $2n$ terms of $(a_n)$. By comparing each term of LHS and RHS of $f(X)=g(X)\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_iX^i$ (mod $2n$), we get $2n$ equations. Since there is $2n$ unknown coefficients, we can determine all of them if and only if the $2n$ equations are linearly independent each other.

According to Berlekamp Massey Algorithm, we can always determine $f(X)$ and $g(X)$ from first $2n$ term of $(a_n)$.

Why the euqations we get from $f(X)=g(X)\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_iX^i$ (mod $X^{2N}$) are always linearly independent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the recurrence is of lower order than $n$, the equations won't be linearly independent.

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: I understand what you mean. If f and g are not coprime,  threre are multiple solutions. But Berlekamp Massey algorithm ensure the coprimeness by extended Euclidian algorithm.  This was confusing me. Thank you.